# Global instance variable or local instance variable declaration which one better in java

Tags: java

In my class I have complex method, in that method I have called many methods and passed some instance variable, even I passed more then 6 instance variable as parameter.

I thought that may be I can declare those instance parameter as global instance variable so that access it directly within method.

Is it better approach to use global instance variable?

For example :

```
Process 1 :

    public class PostIncExample {

    public void test() {
        Test1 test = findById();
        Test2 test2 = findOne();
        Test3 test3 = fildOne();
        Lis<Test4> test4 = findAll();
    }

    private void redemp(Test1 test, Test2 test2, Test3 test3, Lis<Test4> test4) {

    }

    private void accuM(Test1 test, Test2 test2, Test3 test3, Lis<Test4> test4) {

    }

}

Process 2 :

public class PostIncExample {
    Test1 test;
    Test2 test2;
    Test3 test3;
    Lis<Test4> test4;


    public void test() {
        test = findById();
        test2 = findOne();
        test3 = fildOne();
        test4 = findAll();
    }

    private void redemp() {
        // Used above instance directly here
    }

    private void accuM() {
        // Used above instance directly here
    }

}
```

Which process is better?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to NOT use global variables that you are manipulating within methods. It makes it harder to debug later if some other outside method modifies the variable. Global variables are good for things like constants.